# Youtube iframe autoplay embed

Tags: youtube, mybb

I am using a plugin for myBB called Profile Music Plugin which can be found here http://community.mybb.com/mods.php?action=view&pid=75

I need help with making it able to autoplay in the profile.

EDIT:

The code for this currently is:

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$youtubeid}" autoplay="1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
```

I need help on making this autoplay

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a [mcve]. Please show the code which is not working - for example include the rendered output of that profile plugin. And add more details, for example which version of myBB you are running.

Comment: Done. I thope that is enough information.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#Manual_IFrame_Embeds) says that you have to specify `autoplay` as url parameter:

```
 <iframe width="300" height="200"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$youtubeid}?autoplay=1" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

Comment: It still isn't autoplaying

Comment: You have to replace `{$youtubeid}` with a specific video id.

Comment: It's part of a plugin so it does that for any video that a user puts.

Comment: So if the plugin replaces the `{$youtubeid}` please post an example of the html which goes to the browser and does not work. Nobody can guess your problem. Another idea would be to look at the browsers dev tools (usually activated with F12) and look for script or ressource errors.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm confused by your first question